# given a timezone string, how can i set a date object to that TZ in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, timezone

I have this code:

```
toolFilters.filter('dateAccordingToTimeZone', function($filter) {
    // Gets the number of milliseconds pass from 1970 and convert it to time according to given timezone, currently
    // supported “Asia/Jerusalem” and “America/Los_Angeles”
    return function(milliSeconds, timeZoneId) {
        if (milliSeconds == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        var d = new Date();

        var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();

        if ((timeZoneId == "Asia/Jerusalem") || (timeZoneId == "IL")) {
            return $filter('date')(milliSeconds, 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss', '+0200');
        } else if ((timeZoneId == "America/Los_Angeles")) {
            return $filter('date')(milliSeconds, 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss', 'PST');
        } else {
            return $filter('date')(milliSeconds, 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss');
        }
    };
})
```

I try to make it more generic, so I created a `Date()` object but I cannot set its TZ with the given `TZ string`. How can I do it?

Then I want to use `getTimezoneOffset()`

Comment: Look at using moment.js library with timezone plugin

Comment: Date objects don't have a timezone, they are always UTC. You can adjust the time value though by a particular offset so it represents another timezone, however you need to work out what offset applies at a particular moment in time and consider daylight saving.

Comment: @RobG I cannot make it generic somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the timezone string is a valid [IANA timezone identifier](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) and the [Intl object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) is supported, you can use [*Date.prototype.toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) with an appropriate language code, e.g.

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-GB', {timeZone:'America/Los_Angeles', timeZoneName:'short'}));
console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-GB', {timeZone:'Asia/Jerusalem', timeZoneName:'short'}));
console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-GB', {timeZone:'UTC', timeZoneName:'short'}));
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use a library. Writing your own function to support all regions, timezones and daylight saving shifts is likely not reasonable, though the IANA timezone database is freely available if you wish to do that.

#### TLDR;

An offset is simply the difference between a local time (however that is determined) and UTC. A timezone is a region that observes the same timezone offset. The region and offset are typically determined by some administrative body such as a regional or national government.

A particular place may be in more than one timezone and have more than one offset depending on the date, e.g. Sydney, Australia uses Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST) which is UTC+1000 during winter and Australian Eastern Daylight Time (AEDT) which is UTC+1100 during summer, so two different offsets and two different timezones. Brisbane, Australia uses AEST all year round, so one offset and one timezone. Perth, Australia, has dabbled with daylight saving from time to time. Norfolk Island changed its offset from +11:12 in 1951, then to +1030 to +11:00 in 2015, and observed daylight saving for year in the 1970s.

There is no standard for naming timezones, though the IANA names are becoming a *de facto* standard. There is also no way to reliably determine the timezone from the offset, though a reasonable guess can be made based on summer and winter offsets that is correct most of the time (but that will not do in a general case where it must be correct).

Typically, dates are exchanged using UTC (zero offset), with an adjustment made for display purposes only. This can create issues where the offset should be ignored, e.g. birthdays. Someone born in India at 04:30 in the morning of 1 Jan 2018 does not, when in New York, say they were born on 31 Dec 2017, even though that was the date in New York at the moment they were born.

Comment: I have tried to use moment-tz.js but it fails to parse timezone `GMT-08:00`

Comment: @EladBenda—your OP is about presenting timestamps based on timezone names like "Asia/Jerusalem" that appear to be IANA compliant. Parsing different format timezones is a different question. If you have an offset like GMT-08:00, that can be parsed and applied directly to the Date. You may need to ask another question.